# MeteorJS Error Class

Tags: error-handling, meteor

In some code, run on the client, loaded in a 'lib' sub-folder, i'm trying to throw a `Meteor.Error()` but instead I'm getting something funky...

```
*Uncaught [object Object]*
```

http://screencast.com/t/0WipUFRs

Here's my code:

```
throw new Meteor.Error(500, 'the auction was not found');
```

Is this a loading order issue of some sort?  Or is my syntax wrong? or what?

- Meteorite version 0.4.9
- Meteor version 0.5.9 (git checkout)

Comment: Not related to your question: return statements after throwing exceptions are dead code and can be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deprecated - this is no longer an issue with Meteor past v 0.6.3